# Tell application screen is not zoomed

Tags: macos, applescript, zoom

When using OS X's native zoom, is there any way (perhaps using AppleScript) to fool an application into thinking the screen is not being zoomed?

Something like

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application "Decoder" that screen_zoom is false
```

In this case I am trying to view a video application zoomed in, but if I zoom in, it stops and says "Please undo screen zoom" (probably for legal reasons or something silly)

The application's window size is also forcably limted.

The application is [Decoder](https://itunes.apple.com/za/app/decoder/id463683916?mt=12) by Multichoice Mobile Operations (Pty) Ltd.

Comment: That is contradicting requirement.  One is to ask system to actual use the zoom function, but the other is to have it at the same time pretend (report to all applications) it is not using it?

Comment: Please can you include a link to the developers of the Decoder application. This will likely help attract more informed answers.

Comment: Tried ctrl-scroll up/down? Not very nice, but simulates what you want.

Comment: Just so we fully understand the problem can you tell us why you want to zoom the window?

Answer (score 1):

### Technical Limits

No, it is not possible to tell one application to ignore the zoom state of the screen.

By complaining the application is taking additional steps to both detect and notify you of the zoom condition; this is not normal.

That the application complains, suggests the developers encountered problems when the screen was zoomed.

It is possible the "Decoder" application is using the screen buffer in some way intrinsic to its purpose. It may be writing directly to memory buffers or using other techniques to display video that rely on the display resolution being understood and constant.

### Contacting Support

Have you tried contacting the developers of [Decoder](https://itunes.apple.com/za/app/decoder/id463683916?mt=12) directly? Have you logged a bug with their support?

Most enterprise software is highly configurable and may include hidden options to support what you need.

Comment: I am 100% percent sure they are limiting the size and zoom just for enterprise reasons, NOT technical reasons

Comment: Regardless of the reason, it remains impossible to tell one application to ignore the zoom state of the screen. You need to modify the application's code or find an alternative less restricted application.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Do you have any advice for me on how to modify a Mac Application's code? Does it need to be decomplied?

Comment: To modify it, first it would have to not be a signed application -- and if you're correct that they're limiting something for enterprise reasons, it's probable that the application is signed. If the app comes from the App Store, it's definitely signed. Changes to unsigned applications generally render them unable to be loaded.

Comment: To find the app, go to App store and search "Decoder". The app has the text "DSTV Decoder" on the logo @mah

Comment: @GrahamMiln So is it possible to tell *all* applications that the screen is not zoomed?

Comment: No it is not possible. At the application level, it appears the Accessibility API is fairly limited: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXIntro/OSXAXintro.html